# How can I delete all the configs from git?

Tags: git, github

Someone was using my PC to study git/github and now all my commits show up in my profile with this person as "author". How do I clear git bash login history?

I already tried changing the config --global and nothing changes

Comment: "Someone was using my PC to study" it is so easy to set up a new user on a computer.  Never share a login, it's a big mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about changing the commit author, so the `user.name` and `user.email` [git configuration settings](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

There are multiple places where these settings can be changed:

- System (`git config --system`), located in `/etc/gitconfig`
- Global (`git config --global`), located in `~/.config/git/config` or `~/.gitconfig`
- Local ie per repository (`git config --local`), located in `.git/config`

You can inspect the current value of the setting by typing e.g.

```
 git config --show-origin --show-scope user.email
```

Find the level where the settings were changed, and revert the change by either

- modifying the respective file (`git config --local --edit`)
- through a command (`git config --local user.name "Your Name"`
- resetting the setting on that level (`git config --local --unset user.config`) to use the value from the upper level (local -> global -> system)

I suggest keeping the `system` level unset and configuring these kind of things on the `global` (i.e. per user) level, especially if you intend to share that computer again.